# Spring Boot Response Entity Is Returning Null While Unit Testing Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, response, resttemplate, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to unit test my Controller which returns a ResponseEntity but when I'm testing it using restTemplate the value in **response** is coming as null. Please help.

UserControllerTest :

```
@MockBean
RoleService roleService;
@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
@Test
public void testGetAllRoles() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Role role = new Role(1l, "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN", "Super Admin");
    roleList.add(role);
    User user = new User("FirstName", "LastName", "testEmail", "credential", roleList);

    when(roleService.getAllRoles()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(role));

    ResponseEntity<List<Role>> response = restTemplate.exchange("/user/getAllRoles", GET,
            loggedInAs("testEmail", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Role>>() {
            });

    assertEquals(response.getStatusCode().value(), HttpStatus.OK.value());
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    //assertEquals(response.getBody().get(0).getCode(), role.getCode());
}
```

UserController:

```
@Autowired
RoleService roleService;
@GetMapping("/user/getAllRoles")
@Operation(summary = "get a list of all Roles")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SALES_USER')")
public ResponseEntity<List<Role>> getAllRoles() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    return responseHelper.response(null, roleService.getAllRoles(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

RoleService:

```
@Override
public List<Role> getAllRoles() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findAll();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roles)) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(env.getProperty(ConstantsUtil.APP_MODULE_ROLE), env.getProperty(ConstantsUtil.ROLE_NOT_FOUND));
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Role:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;

@Column(name = "code", length = 50)
private String code;

@Column(name = "description", length = 100)
private String description;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return code;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Did you debug and a request from test, stop in controller ?

Comment: Yes, I've debugged , This is what is shown in response while debugging : 

response = "<200,[Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Content-Length:"0", Date:"Sun, 31 Jul 2022 09:09:17 GMT", Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", Connection:"keep-alive"]>"

Comment: ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.
  getForEntity(FOO_RESOURCE_URL + "/1", String.class); use getForEntity

Comment: @MaximBezmen , What does it means actually I'm new to Spring Boot . Can you please explain what should I need to do.

Comment: getForEntity this is Retrieve an entity by doing a GET on the specified URL. The response is converted and stored in an ResponseEntity.

Comment: Which line should I edit ? Can you write the comparison of previous and new code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need replace your test on this:

```
List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
        Role role = new Role(1l, "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN", "Super Admin");
        roleList.add(role);
        User user = new User("FirstName", "LastName", "testEmail", "credential", roleList);

        when(roleService.getAllRoles()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(role));

        ResponseEntity<Object[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/user/getAllRoles", Object[].class);
        Object[] objects = response.getBody();

        assertEquals(response.getStatusCode().value(), HttpStatus.OK.value());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Use [it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html)

Comment: I've used this and while running I'm getting this error :        

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class [Ljava.lang.Object;] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:

Comment: also you can use this way for list objects  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list   or try use getForObject instead of getForEntity